# Can not get SQLAlchemy installed on win10

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, windows-10

Win10, python3.5.6 and I have Conda installed.

When I try to install SQLAlchemy like follows using cmd in CLI, I get errors.

```
pip install SQLAlchemy
  copying lib\sqlalchemy\testing\suite\test_update_delete.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.5\sqlalchemy\testing\suite
  copying lib\sqlalchemy\testing\suite\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.5\sqlalchemy\testing\suite
  running build_ext
  error: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified

Failed building wheel for SQLAlchemy

Command "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\python.exe -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='C:\\Users\\xby\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-ebkmu2f_\\SQLAlchemy\\setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install --record C:\Users\xby\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-b0kltmo1\install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile" failed with error code 1 in C:\Users\xby\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-ebkmu2f_\SQLAlchemy\
```

Can anyone give me a clue? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

OK, finally I get this tricky problem solved.

It's all because of lack of compiler on the windows system, because I didn't install VS or any of other compilers.

So I managed to install a substitute one:
http://mingw-w64.org
after installed, run cmd like this(for 64bit system):

```
python setup.py install  build --compiler=mingw64
```

ofter this, every thing works smoothly.
Hope this helps to someone get stuck as me.